# Where to put static URL in android project?

Tags: android, static, preference

I have an android app that connects to a server at a static URL. I want to figure out where to put the url so that I can access it form my app.

The consensus seems to be that `values/strings.xml` is the way to go. However, I'm afraid that a single file for all of my static values could get unwieldy. Is there a way to use multiple different files for different types of strings (UI, internals, etc)? If I simply make different files, will android be smart about it and import them all? Is there an accepted canonical way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can provide many different XML files and name them the way you see fit. It's the resource qualifiers (the folder name) that matters.

Provide your string resource and you will be fine.

However, since your URI is static, I'd put them as a static final variable instead, in code. It will be easier to call it from places where supplying a Context may not be the best approach. And let's face it, there is probably no reason to make it a String resource and have to call it through the overhead of the resource system unless you need it in a XML layout, for example.